# Why doesn't subsequences of a partial sum always converge to the same value of the convergent sequence of partial sums

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

What I mean is, let $A_n = \sum_1^na_k$

Assume $A_n$ is convergent. Then by sequences property I would expect $A_{n_{k}}$ to converge to the same value.

But let $a_k = (-1)^n \frac{1}{n}$

This sequence is conditionally convergent so I can easily alter it's value that it converges to. Wouldn't this be a contradiction?

Comment: Nah, its no contradiction.  What's worse is I can make it diverge by rearranging the terms.  This is easily done by taking the sum over the positive terms until it is larger than one, then take the sum over the negative terms until it is less than zero, then take the sum over the positive terms... and this will always be possible ***because*** it converges conditionally (the absolute value of the terms diverge, so I can always reach whatever value I want, then switch it up, so it won't converge.  Same argument will allow it to converge to any value as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A_n=\sum_{1}^{n}a_k$ is a convergent sequence, then every subsequence $A_{n_k}$ is also convergent and has the same limit.

The point about conditionally convergent series is that if you *change the order of the terms* you can obtain different results. That's not the same as taking subsequences of $A_n$.

Answer (score 1):

It does. You can start with the conditionally convergent series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{1}{k}$ and rearrange it so that it will converge to something else but rearrangement is not the same as passing to a subsequence. Let's say we rearrange it as follow:

$$ -1 -\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{4} + \dots $$

The corresponding sequence of partial sums is given by

$$ -1, -1 - \frac{1}{3}, -1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2}, \dots $$

while the sequence of the partial sums of the original series is given by

$$ -1, -1 + \frac{1}{2}, -1 + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3}, \dots $$

You can see that the former is not a subsequence of the latter.